# Jenkins BlueOcean missing parameters for plugins as "Send build artifacts over SSH"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I was wondering, I am creating a pipeline within the `BlueOcean editor` and was not able to configure the step "Send build artifacts over SSH" due to missing parameters.

Am I missing something, or are there compatibility issues?

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I was expecting more parameters as you can see here (for instance the parameter "remoteDirectorySDF")...: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/publish-over-ssh/#publish-over-ssh

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has the same problem, here is my result.

As I found out, it is not possible at the moment. However, there is a workaround if you add this functionality straight into your Jenkinsfile.

Best,
Martin